# Computed Style not working with overwritten CSS variables

Tags: javascript, html, css, getcomputedstyle

I'm making a website search engine like Google, and when a thing is visited I want to it turn green and change a tooltip. I use `:visited` to do that, and the code changes it to purple and sets a variable `--visitedBSA` to true.

The problem is, in my JavaScript, using `getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("link1")).getPropertyValue("--visitedBSA")` gives the :root value, not the updated value after visiting the website. Thus, when updating the tooltip, its "not visited" and sets the tooltip to "not visited" instead of "visited"

```js
var mousePos = {
  x: undefined,
  y: undefined
};

window.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  mousePos = {
    x: event.clientX,
    y: event.clientY
  };

  document.getElementById("tt").style.left = mousePos.x + 10;
  document.getElementById("tt").style.top = mousePos.y + 10;
  var cs = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("link1"))

  console.log(cs.getPropertyValue('--visitedLink1'))

  if (cs.getPropertyValue('--visitedLink1') == "true") {
    document.getElementById("tt").innerHTML = "Visited"
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  --visitLink1: false;
}

a {
  color: blue;
}

#link1:visited {
  --visitBSA: true;
  color: purple;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: wheat;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

a:hover~.tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Search</h1>
<div class="text">Link 1: <a id="link1" href="https://www.scouting.org">scouting.com</a>
  <div id="tt" class="tooltip">Not visited</div> troop.</div>
```

Comment: For security, nothing is allowed to access styles applied by `:visited`, as it would allow an attacker to determine what URLs someone has visited. That includes getting computed styles from JavaScript.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just check if the color of the link is purple using the getComputedStyle(). Or add a click event listener on each link like this-

```js
link.addEventListener("click", e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   link.style.setProperty("--visitedLink1", "true")
   window.open(link.href, "_blank")
})
```

Info- You were assigning `--visitedBSA` to true in `a:visited` but searching for `--visitedLink1 === "true"` in js

Edit- You still cannot access any CSS property declared in `:visited` using javascript `getComputedStyle()` so the best option would be to use the hacky solution prescribed at the beginning (overriding each link's click event)

Comment: You cannot access `:visited` styles from JS, period.

Comment: I have now realised that but this fix still works

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `:visited` styles from JavaScript, [for security/privacy reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector).

In addition, it appears that CSS custom properties ("CSS vars") cannot be set in `:visited` styles. I suppose because of the complexity of keeping track of where they are used and preventing access.

This snippet shows that you cannot access changed styles:

```js
const link = document.querySelector("#link")
const button = document.querySelector("#button")

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // rgb(0, 0, 255) is blue
  console.log(getComputedStyle(link).color)
});
```

```css
a {
  color: blue;
}

a:visited {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<a id="link" href="https://example.com">example.com</a>
<button id="button">Log style</button>
```

And this one shows that CSS custom properties are not settable:

```css
a {
  color: var(--color);
}

a {
  --color: blue;
}

a:visited {
  --color: purple;
  /* This works fine: */
  /* color: purple; */
}

a:hover {
  /* As does this: */
  --color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://example.com">example.com</a>
```